# python to mysql (MariaDB) insert query with variable error

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, sql-insert

I am trying use insert query to write to a MariaDB database using Python(3.6).

I am able to successfully connect to the database but insert query with variable doesn't seem to work. But, when I use insert query directly inside .execute() without variable, it seems to work.

```
script = "insert INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES (%s)"
val=("911")
mycursor.execute(script,val)
```

I am getting following programming error for above code:

ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Any pointers in right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to set the [paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) to `'format'` or you have to use another paramstyle. In MySQL Connector/Python e.g. the default paramstyle is `'pyformat'` and not `'format'`.

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem

```
>>> val=("911")
>>> type(val)
<class 'str'>
>>> val
'911'
```

In Python3, redundant parentheses will be removed so it will interpret it as a string and not a tuple, which is required when working with `%s`. You need to use `val=('911",)` to force val to be of type tuple

```
>>> val=("911",)
>>> type(val)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> val
('911',)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
script = "insert INTO Table1 (Column1) VALUES ('%s')"
val=("911")
mycursor.execute(script,val)
```

Try this, I used to have similar issues with sqlite3.